# PrimeNG datatable not editable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Hi I'm trying to use primeNG for datatable but the output is just a basic table with no properties of it applied.
Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';     //accordion and accordion tab
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';  
import {DataTableModule} from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import {SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { sampleProducts } from './products';

@Component({
  selector: 'data-grid',
  templateUrl: './data-grid.html'
})
export class DataGridComponent {
  private data: any[] = sampleProducts;
}
```

template:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" [editable]="true">
<p-column field="PayScaleArea" header="PayScaleArea"></p-column>
<p-column field="PayScaleTypeCode" header="PayScaleTypeCode" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="MeritPercentage" header="MeritPercentage" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
<p-column field="CreatedBy" header="CreatedBy"></p-column>
<p-column field="CreatedDate" header="CreatedDate"></p-column>
```

app.module:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';     //accordion and accordion tab
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/primeng';  
import {DataTableModule} from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import {SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { DataGridComponent } from './data-grid.component';


@NgModule({
   bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
   declarations: [AppComponent,DataGridComponent],
   imports:      [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, AccordionModule,DataTableModule,SharedModule]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

output:
Looks like normal table.
Is there anything missing in the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try setting the columns as editable too? like:

```
 <p-column field="PayScaleArea" header="PayScaleArea" [editable]="true"></p-column>
```

Comment: And also editable property displays 2 rows for each row,one display and other in edit mode, how do we enable in line editing?

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have the problem ?

I created this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/336CtXteAvLJbvncLrUO?p=preview) with your code where I just added `[editable]="true"` for each `p-column` and everything seems to be ok (sorting and editing data), isn't it ?

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" [editable]="true">
  <p-column field="PayScaleArea" header="PayScaleArea" [editable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="PayScaleTypeCode" header="PayScaleTypeCode" [sortable]="true" [editable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="MeritPercentage" header="MeritPercentage" [sortable]="true" [editable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="CreatedBy" header="CreatedBy" [editable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="CreatedDate" header="CreatedDate" [editable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```